# Separating the duplicating data in new columns in tidyverse

Tags: r, tidyverse

I have a large data base and many data are duplicated and I want o generate two new columns for these data.

Here is a brief of data

```html
df <- tribble(~ID, ~Code,
              1, "p",
              1, "p",
              2, "f",
              3, "p",
              2, "p",
              3, "f",
              4, "f",
              4, "p",
              6, "p")
```

I would like to get the following data:

```html
 Out1 Out2
1 p p
2 f p
3 p f
4 f p
5 p NA
```

I struggled to run separate in tidyverse to do it. Any help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way to do it is:

```
df %>%
 group_by(ID) %>%
 mutate(temp = paste0("Out", seq_along(ID))) %>%
 spread(temp, Code)

     ID Out1  Out2 
  <dbl> <chr> <chr>
1     1 p     p    
2     2 f     p    
3     3 p     f    
4     4 f     p    
5     6 p     <NA>
```

If you want to change also the ID:

```
df %>%
 group_by(ID) %>%
 mutate(temp = paste0("Out", seq_along(ID))) %>%
 spread(temp, Code) %>%
 ungroup() %>%
 mutate(ID = seq_along(ID))

     ID Out1  Out2 
  <int> <chr> <chr>
1     1 p     p    
2     2 f     p    
3     3 p     f    
4     4 f     p    
5     5 p     <NA>
```